# How to create a proper .json file for a custom Minecraft .jar?

Tags: java, minecraft

I am working on a custom Minecraft client as a personal project, not anything commercial, and I want to try launching it from the launcher. I am working on it in Eclipse, my Java IDE, and it runs fine in there. I exported the client folder as a jar from there, and then got stuck. I know I can't launch it without a proper json, but the problem that I am having is that I don't know what to put into it. I know I name the jar and json files the same as I name the folder, but with their respective file endings, and that I put the files into the folder in the versions folder. I have tried looking stuff up and I have found solutions that have worked for other people, such as deleting these lines from the 1.12 json:

```
   "downloads":{
      "client":{
         "sha1":"909823f9c467f9934687f136bc95a667a0d19d7f",
         "size":10177098,
         "url":"https://launcher.mojang.com/v1/objects/909823f9c467f9934687f136bc95a667a0d19d7f/client.jar"
      },
      "server":{
         "sha1":"8494e844e911ea0d63878f64da9dcc21f53a3463",
         "size":30202458,
         "url":"https://launcher.mojang.com/v1/objects/8494e844e911ea0d63878f64da9dcc21f53a3463/server.jar"
      }
   },
```

among other solutions that worked for others, but not me. I really want to finally get the json to work, and I don't know how I would get it set up properly. What would be the changes necessary for my modded .jar to work? is there any way to launch without a jar? I have been at this for days, so any help is very appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You want to make sure the ID is your jar files name, and that worked for me, however to let you know, the client I'm running is 1.16.3

[image]